# Getopt shift optarg

Tags: c, getopt

I need to call my program like this:

```
./program hello -r foo bar
```

I take hello out of argv[1], but i am having trouble with value bar, also should i change "r:" to something else?

```
while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "r:")) != -1){
   switch(i){
   ...
   case 'r':
     var_foo = optarg;
     //shell like argument shift here?
     var_bar = optarg;
     break;
...}
```

I know I could do this with passing through argv, but is there a way to do it with getopt similar way as in bash?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something like `argv[optind++]`?

Answer (score 8):

`bar` is not an option argument in the eyes of `getopt`. Rather, GNU `getopt` *rearranges* the positional arguments so that at the end of the processing, you have `argv[3]` being "hello" and `argv[4]` being "bar". Basically, when you're done getopting, you still have positional arguments `[optind, argc)` to process:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
     {
         int c;
         while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, ...)) != -1) { /* ... */ }
     }

     for (int i = optind; i != argc; ++i)
     {
         // have positional argument argv[i]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you're using [GNU `getopt()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) or not, and if you are, whether `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set in the environment.

Classically (meaning non-GNU [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)), all the option arguments must precede any non-option (file name) arguments.  That would mean you have four non-option arguments.

If you have GNU `getopt()` and do not have `POSIXLY_CORRECT` set, then it will process option arguments anywhere on the command line.  In that case, you'd have one option, `-r` with the argument value `foo`, and two non-option arguments (`hello` and `bar`).

To get Classic `getopt()` to recognize the `-r`, you'd have to require the first (non-option) argument and only then call `getopt()` at all:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cmd = argv[1];
    int   opt;

    argv[1] = argv[0];
    argv++;
    argc--;

    while ((opt = getopt(argv, argc, "r:")) != EOF)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'r':
            ...capture optarg...
            break;
        default:
            ...report error....
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        process_non_option_argument(cmd, argv[i]);

    return(0);
}
```

GNU `getopt` can also return non-option arguments if you enable it to do so.  Other than that, the `bar` argument will always be treated as a non-option argument.